# Minimum Weighted Path Tree of an Undirected Graph

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory

Assume that we have an undirected graph G=(V,E) and we have two nodes S and X.

1. Can we come up with an algorithm such that the largest weight of the edge on the path from S to X is minimized? Note that it is not the shortest path algorithm since we are not interested in minimizing their sum.
2. What is the complexity of this algorithm?
3. Is the minimum spanning tree algorithm (such as Prim) is a solution for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if minimum spanning tree will solve it or not, but it's certainly solvable by making some modifications to Dijkstra's algorithm.

Define the "length" of a path as the maximum edge in that path. Now find the shortest path from S to X using Dijkstra's algorithm. This is the path you are looking for.
Complexity is `O((N+M)log N)` if you use a binary heap and `O(N * log N + M)` with a Fibonacci heap.

Note that for this new definition of path length, if the length of a path is `l`, then adding an edge to the end of the path will not decrease it's length, since the maximum edge in that path can only increase. This property is necessary for Dijkstra's algorithm to work correctly.

For instance, if you were looking for the path with the shortest edge, then Dijkstra's algorithm will fail just like it fails when there are negative edges in the graph.

Comment: Now think of a graph V=(V1,v2,v3) and E=((v1,v2,2),(v2,v3,2),(v1,v3,3)). Let S=v2 and X=v3. Dijkstra will return (v1,v3) with shortest path of 3 in total but the answer is (v1,v2) and (v2,v3) with a path of 4, which consists 2 edges with weights of 2. So in this problem, we expect the latter. Could you explain please that the modified Dijkstra algorithm that you offer gives the correct answer?

Comment: @kemal4488 I think you meant S=v1. Anyways, normal Dijkstra will return shortest path as 3, but the new Dijkstra where you measure the maximum edge will provide 2. Here's how it goes. You look at adjacent nodes from v1. v2 is at distance 2 & v3 is at distance 3. We take the closest v2. v2 has a neighbor v3 at dist 2. Now, in normal Dijkstra the new distance would be 2 + 2. But, in our Dijkstra, the new distance is max(2, 2). Since max(2, 2) is less than v3's original distance 3, we update it. You see how you get the correct answer in the end?

Comment: Yes, in the example S=v1 and X=v3. I now understand what you have meant. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use minimum spanning tree (Prim's algorithm) to solve this problem. You will start with vertex `S`, then continue to build the tree using Prim's algorithm until you find `X`. Complexity will be O((V+E)*logV).
It will work because in the prim's algorithm you always choose the edge with minimum weight first.

Comment: Today, it was a part of the question in my proficiency exam and your answer is exactly what I did. I hope (and believe) this is a solution alternative. Thank you.

Comment: @kemal4488 if you look at the merlyn answer and prim's algorithm they actually are closely related.